# This error happens for every npm installation: "npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined."

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

**Intro**

Greetings, all!

I'm on a dual boot system where Node, NPM, and the like worked well in Windows 7, but since Win7 has stopped booting - perhaps due to hardware problems - that leaves Windows 10.

Every time I try using npm install (or some variant, like npm i -g), I get an error at least similar to what is listed below.  This has prevented me from using npm i to get the newest npm.

I have tried finding and deleting package.json, but I'm unsure *which* package.json to remove.  There was one in C:\users\\ but that has since been deleted.  Moving or deleting node_modules from my node or npm directory hasn't fixed the problem.

I've tried checking the Internet for various solutions to this problem, including installing the latest NodeJS.

**Versions**

*Obtained via node -v and npm -v.*

Node: 10.16

NPM: 6.9

**This is the log which displays upon running npm i -g npm.**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'F:\\NodeJS\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'F:\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'npm',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose npm-session c2c7a7280bf360c8
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for npm@latest Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 32ms
10 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
10 verbose stack     at regFetch (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\index.js:76:23)
10 verbose stack     at fetchPackument (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\packument.js:42:10)
10 verbose stack     at packument (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\packument.js:20:10)
10 verbose stack     at getManifest (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:22:10)
10 verbose stack     at manifest (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:13:10)
10 verbose stack     at Object.manifest (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\index.js:17:12)
10 verbose stack     at Object.Fetcher#manifest [as manifest] (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\genfun\lib\genfun.js:15:38)
10 verbose stack     at manifest (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetch.js:23:18)
10 verbose stack     at pinflight (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\manifest.js:24:12)
10 verbose stack     at F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:29:24
10 verbose stack     at Promise._execute (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:313:9)
10 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
10 verbose stack     at new Promise (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
10 verbose stack     at _inflight (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:28:25)
10 verbose stack     at F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:22:14
10 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (F:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\Gec
12 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
13 verbose argv "F:\\NodeJS\\node.exe" "F:\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "npm" "-g"
14 verbose node v10.16.0
15 verbose npm  v6.9.0
16 error Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Same error even today, tried reinstall, restart, upgrade to 12x, downgrade to 10.16, moving out of proxy network still facing error `silly fetchPackageMetaData error for http_server@latest Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined` and `verbose stack     at regFetch (C:\nodejs\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\index.js:76:23)`

Comment: Uninstalled node and installed v9.11.2 with npm v5.6.0, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `nodejs` 10.16.0 (Windows x64 version) and `npm` 6.9.0. After uninstalling and downgrading to `nodejs` 10.15.3 and `npm` 6.4.1 `npm i` seems to work correctly again.